# How do you identify a zombie process?

Tags: process, ubuntu-9.10

When login through a terminal into my Ubuntu 9.10 Server, I see the following message:

```
=> There is 1 zombie process.
```

How can I identify this zombie process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `ps` command.  I almost always use `ps auxwww`.

```
$ ps auxwww
USER       PID %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
exegete  22199   0.0  0.2    79204   3280 s000  Z     9:16AM   0:00.78 vi
exegete  22185   0.0  0.0    75968    968 s000  S     9:16AM   0:00.01 -bash
```

According to the docs, a "Z" in the `STAT` column indicates a zombie process.  Check the man pages:  `man ps`

Comment: I used "ps l | grep Z" and killed the PPID.  Killing the PID doesn't do the job, going after the parent does the trick.

Comment: You would likely have to use a `kill -9`, but even then zombies don't always respond.  Sometimes you are forced to reboot.

Comment: Zombies are already dead, waiting for parent to read their status.  Killing them, with any signal, doesn't do anything. It's not a process, just a process slot. Killing the parent (PPID) makes init (PID 1) the zombie's parent, which then reaps it (reads status) - zombie gone.

Comment: Sometimes I can't tell if I'm reading a Minecraft stack exchange, or Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

I often get that if I closed my SSH session without logging out, then logged back in before another process (init) adopted the processes that were running in the previous session.

However after a few minutes if you go back and do a `top` there will be no zombie processes.